# How to correctly use a generator to skip over iterations

Tags: python, performance, iteration, generator, combinations

I want to find out all the possible combinations of 9 darts that sum to 501 with the last dart being a double. Here is more info on the [9-Dart Finish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-dart_finish).

I have set up the following program to create a generator to loop over every iteration to satisfy all the conditions. [According to Steve Crook](http://blog.stmellion.org/?p=273), it took him 4,585,142,217,282,816 iterations to come up with every combination and this would take a very long time. I have tried ignoring 1 for the first dart, but I was waiting a very long time just to skip over those combinations.

I added a limit for debugging, just to see if I could find any possible combinations. After 1,000,000,000 I could not find any... There has got to be a more efficient way.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import itertools
import datetime
import time

DEBUG = False

sys_time_ms=lambda:int(round(time.time()*1000))
duration=lambda start,end:datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=(end-start))
str_matrix=lambda m:'\n'.join(','.join(str(c) for c in r) for r in m)

sgl = range(1,21)           # single sections
dbl = map(lambda x:x*2,sgl) # double sections
tpl = map(lambda x:x*3,sgl) # triple sections
bul = [25,50]               # center ring and bull's eye
all = sorted(list(itertools.chain(sgl,dbl,tpl,bul)))

iter_remain  = 1000000000
darts        = list(itertools.chain(list(itertools.repeat(all, 8)),[dbl]))
comboGen     = itertools.product(*darts)
found_count  = 0
start        = sys_time_ms()

if DEBUG: print str_matrix(darts)

while True:
    if iter_remain > 0:
        try:
            combo = next(comboGen)
            if combo[0] > 1 and sum(combo) == 501:
                found_count += 1
        except StopIteration:
            print 'Reached ITERATION_LIMIT'
            break
    else:
        break
    iter_remain -= 1
end = sys_time_ms()

print 'Combinations found: {} in ({})'\
    .format(found_count, duration(start,end))
```

For example, the above program took about 5.5 minutes over one billion iterations and did not find a single combination that summed to to 501.

> Combinations found: 0 in (0:05:35.439000)

The `darts` matrix should look like this:

```
DART_1 [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 21, 22, 24, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 51, 54, 57, 60]
DART_2 [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 21, 22, 24, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 51, 54, 57, 60]
DART_3 [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 21, 22, 24, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 51, 54, 57, 60]
DART_4 [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 21, 22, 24, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 51, 54, 57, 60]
DART_5 [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 21, 22, 24, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 51, 54, 57, 60]
DART_6 [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 21, 22, 24, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 51, 54, 57, 60]
DART_7 [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 21, 22, 24, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 51, 54, 57, 60]
DART_8 [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 21, 22, 24, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 51, 54, 57, 60]
DART_9 [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
```

Comment: 60 * 8 = 480. 501 - 480 = 31. Thus you can get rid of all points less than 31 for any of the throws because even a single dart below 31 would mean you can't reach 501 with 9 darts. Just this simple observation would get rid of quite a few combinations, I'd imagine.

Comment: Er, I mean, `501 - 480 = 21`!

Comment: In fact, `24` is the lowest that a single throw can be: `24 + 57 + (60 * 7) = 501`

Comment: Sorry if this seems like spamming, but we can also quite easily deduce that you need at least three 60s. So that just leaves you with figuring out the combination for the remaining six darts, with a much reduced number of possible points for each dart.